# A single operator module in pytorch vs. A basic block of torch.nn

Tags: pytorch, torch

I'm working with pytorch and I made a simple single-operator `nn.module`(model1) below:

```
class conv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,20,5)
    def forward(self,x):
        return(conv1(x))
model1 = conv()
model1(input)
```

and I started to wonder how it is different from a `torch.nn` layer itself.

```
model2 = nn.Conv2d(1,20,5)
model2(input)
```

Does `model1(input)` behave as same as `model2(input)`? If so, how they are different from each other effectively?

```
model3 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(1,20,5))
model2(input)
```

If the difference comes from its class properties, what if I define `model3` like this? Is it fine to treat `model3` as `model1` at any sense?

I tried to investigate their actual class but I'm not really sure what they are.

```
>>> type(model2)
<class 'torch.nn.modules.conv.Conv2d'>
>>> type(model3)
<class 'torch.nn.modules.container.Sequential'>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two elements in your question I would like to answer. First the fact of wrapping a builtin `nn.Module`, and second looking at why you get different results.

They are the same layer and have the same properties. However, what are you doing by using a custom `nn.Module` and `nn.Sequential` is wrapping those layers (in a programming sense), in other words, it doesn't change the underlying layer itself.

The reason why `model1`, `model2`, and `model3` will yield different results given the same input is because all three have been initialized separately. As such their initialization weights are different!